# O(n) list subtraction

Tags: python, bag

When [working on an AoC puzzle](https://github.com/wimglenn/advent-of-code/blob/a7cd62b3c0b2ccb87f9ebc7535fdd0c8ba2b50e4/aoc2015/q24.py#L31-L35), I found I wanted to subtract lists (preserving ordering):

```
def bag_sub(list_big, sublist):
    result = list_big[:]
    for n in sublist:
        result.remove(n)
    return result
```

I didn't like the way the `list.remove` call (which is itself O(n)) is contained within the loop, that seems needlessly inefficient.  So I tried to rewrite it to avoid that:

```
def bag_sub(list_big, sublist):
    c = Counter(sublist)
    result = []
    for k in list_big:
        if k in c:
            c -= Counter({k: 1})
        else:
            result.append(k)
    return result
```

1. Is this now O(n), or does the `Counter.__isub__` usage still screw things up?
2. This approach requires that elements must be hashable, a restriction which the original didn't have.  Is there an O(n) solution which avoids creating this additional restriction?  Does Python have any better "bag" datatype than `collections.Counter`?

You can assume `sublist` is half the length of `list_big`.

Comment: Do these lists have any particular order to them? You can do this in O(n) deterministic time if they're both sorted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with Counter there. You could get the same result more clearly by converting sublist to a set and just checking for membership.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- I think that the Counter is handling duplicates (`bag_sub([foo, foo], [foo]) -> [foo]`)

Comment: @user2357112  No ordering.  I know how to do it in O(n log n) by sorting first, and walking a pair of "pointers" down the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this now O(n), or does the `Counter.__isub__` usage still screw things up?

This would be expected-case O(n), except that when `Counter.__isub__` discards nonpositive values, it goes through *every key* to do so. You're better off just subtracting 1 from the key value the "usual" way and checking `c[k]` instead of `k in c`. (`c[k]` is 0 for `k not in c`, so you don't need an `in` check.)

```
if c[k]:
    c[k] -= 1
else:
    result.append(k)
```

> Is there an O(n) solution which avoids creating this additional restriction?

Only if the inputs are sorted, in which case a standard variant of a mergesort merge can do it.

> Does Python have any better "bag" datatype than `collections.Counter`?

`collections.Counter` is Python's bag.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a Counter, but I'd probably do it slightly differently, and I'd probably do this iteratively...

```
def bag_sub(big_list, sublist):
    sublist_counts = Counter(sublist)
    result = []
    for item in big_list:
        if sublist_counts[item] > 0:
            sublist_counts[item] -= 1
        else:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

This is *very similar* to your solution, but it's probably not efficient to create an entire new counter every time you want to decrement the count on something.<sup>1</sup>

Also, if you don't need to return a list, then consider a generator function...

This works as long as all of the elements in `list_big` and `sublist` can be hashed.  This solution is `O(N + M)` where `N` and `M` are the lengths of `list_big` and `sublist` respectively.

If the elements cannot be hashed, you are out of luck unless you have other constraints (e.g. the inputs are sorted using the same criterion).  If your inputs are sorted, you could do something similar to the merge stage of merge-sort to determine which elements from `bag_sub` are in `sublist`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that `Counter`s also behave a lot like a `defaultdict(int)` so it's perfectly fine to look for an item in a counter that isn't there already.</sup>

Comment: This doesn't handle duplicates the way the original code does.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Ahh, I see now.  I didn't understand what OP was going for.  I've fixed up my solution.

Comment: Better, but you've missed a few nuances of the original code. `c -= Counter({k: 1})` actually operates in-place (on 3.3 and up), and it discards key `k` if the count hits 0, in contrast to something like `c[k] -= 1`, which would preserve the key.

Comment: @wim -- Can you be more specific?  You think that `c -= Counter({k: 1})` is more efficient  than `c[k] -= 1`?

Comment: @mgilson  Oh, kevin [already explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514987/on-list-subtraction/41515152#comment70236406_41515045) what I was talking about.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Huh ... I didn't realize that Counter would drop the key when it dropped to `0`.  I always assumed it would decrement to `0`... Interesting.

Comment: Yeah.  That's why they call it the bag or multiset in the docs.  But they should have implemented <, <=, >, >= for a proper multiset.

Comment: I actually ended up with something pretty similar to yours anyway --> https://github.com/wimglenn/advent-of-code/blob/0402097678c46ec522dc736091acb4ae2b973f2f/aoc2015/q24.py#L32-L39

Comment: A collections.Counter can have explicit 0 values - they're not always dropped - but any nonpositive values will be dropped from the result when you use the multiset operators.

Answer (score -1):

1. Removing an item from a list of length N is O(N) if the list is unordered, because you have to find it.
2. Removing k items from a list of length N, therefore, is O(kN) if we focus on "reasonable" cases where k << N.

So I don't see how you could get it down to O(N).

A concise way to write this:

```
new_list = [x for x in list_big if x not in sublist]
```

But that's still O(kN).

Comment: This doesn't handle duplicates the way the original code does.